# Angular Filtering Multiple Unordered Words

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I am trying to filter elements from a list and I'm trying to filter that element when I write multiple words at once. Right now, I can filter the element if I write the words in their correct order. For example; I can filter `'red book love'` element if I write `'red book'` but I also want to filter it when I write `'red love'`. Here is my code, what should I do to achieve what I want?

HTML:

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="w-100-p pr-8">
            <mat-label>Product</mat-label>
            <input type="text" required matInput [(ngModel)]="product" name="product"
                (input)="onProductSearchChange($event.target.value)" [matAutocomplete]="autoProductId">
            <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="product = null" type="button">
                <mat-icon>block</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #autoProductId="matAutocomplete"
                [displayWith]="displayProduct.bind(this)" (optionSelected)="filterProduct($event.option.value)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let prm of productList" [value]="prm">
                    {{prm?.StockIntegrationCode +' '+ prm?.ProductName}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
```

TS:

```
onProductSearchChange(search: string) {
    let filterValue = (search as any).toLocaleLowerCase("tr");
    if (
        this._adminService.products &&
        this._adminService.products.length > 0
    ) {
        this.productList = this._adminService.products.filter(
            (x) =>
                x.StockIntegrationCode.indexOf(filterValue) >= 0 ||
                (x.ProductName as any)
                    .toLocaleLowerCase("tr")
                    .indexOf(filterValue) >= 0
        );
    }
    if (!search) {
        this.product = null;
        this.productList = this._adminService.products;
    }
}

displayProduct(product: IProduct): string | undefined {
    return product
        ? product.StockIntegrationCode + " - " + product.ProductName
        : "";
}
```

Comment: This should point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916979/angular-search-filter-pipe-for-full-sentence-search-irrespective-of-word-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if you want ALL of the words to match, or just ONE of the words to match, so here's both solutions. I also have no idea what a stock integration code is, so I'm assuming it counts if there's a match in either the code or the name.

**Just one word matches**

```js
  onProductSearchChange(search: string) {
    if (!search) {
      this.product = null;
      this.productList = this._adminService.products;
      return; //Return because the string is empty
    }
    let filterValue = search.toLocaleLowerCase('tr');
    let values = filterValue.split(' ');
    if (this._adminService.products && this._adminService.products.length > 0) {
      this.productList = this._adminService.products.filter((x) => {
        for (const value of values) {
          if (
            x.StockIntegrationCode.includes(value) ||
            x.ProductName.toLocaleLowerCase('tr').includes(value)
          )
            return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
    }
  }
```

**All words match**

```js
  onProductSearchChange(search: string) {
    if (!search) {
      this.product = null;
      this.productList = this._adminService.products;
      return; //Return because the string is empty
    }
    let filterValue = search.toLocaleLowerCase('tr');
    let values = filterValue.split(' ');
    if (this._adminService.products && this._adminService.products.length > 0) {
      this.productList = this._adminService.products.filter((x) => {
        for (const value of values) {
          if (
            !x.StockIntegrationCode.includes(value) &&
            !x.ProductName.toLocaleLowerCase('tr').includes(value)
          )
            return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
    }
  }
```

I just split the filterValue on whitespace, and searched word by word.

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. How can I apply this to a basic search bar that has a code like; 
` applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
        if (this.dataSource) {
            this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
            if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
                this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: You'll probably have to ask a different question and show more code than that. That's pretty meaningless on its own.